# Laravel view not displaying; not as easy as you would think

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Maybe this is something simple, but I'll danged if I can find it. Here is my controller

```
public function index($vendors)
{
    return View::make('orders.index', compact('vendors'));
}

public function indexAll()
{
    $vendors= $this->orderingService->getListByVendor();

    $this->index($vendors);
}
```

Nothing shows up on the page. But if I copy that return View::make to the indexAll method it works fine. And I do mean copy and paste. If I put a dd($vendors) before the return in the index method it dumps out just like you would think. I put a dd in the very first line of the view and still got nothing. There is no errors in the logs. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not returning the return in `indexAll()`. Just modify that last line to be:

```
return $this->index($vendors);
```

Comment: **My god I'm stupid.** I've been messing with this for 2 hours. Thanks! I'll accept the answer as soon as it will let me.

Comment: @Casey `not as easy as you would think` :D The devil is in the details.

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta That title will be there forever, mocking and shaming me. I'm considering changing my name, moving to a country without internet access, and becoming a cobbler